# C# Program Writes to Text File Once But Not a Second Time

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, windows, text

The Program I am writing is for a registration setup. 
It writes to the text file fine, but i want to make sure that if it runs out of power and cuts off(Tablet) that it will have saved the document. It works first time but none thereafter.

Here is my code:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    textBox1.Select();
    var fileSave = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
    fileSave.Close();
    //     DisableCloseButton(); 
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(
    //         "Data Source=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=imis;Integrated Security=True");
    //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    Object returnValue;

    string txtend = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {
        string lastTwoChars = txtend.Substring(txtend.Length - 1);

        returnValue = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"*", "");

        if (lastTwoChars != "*") return;
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Contains(returnValue))
            {
                for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
                {
                    string removelistitem = returnValue.ToString();
                    if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                    {
                        //listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue);

            textBox1.Text = null;
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName);
            foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
                sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());

            sw.Close();
            if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) 
            { 
                DisableCloseButton(); 
            }
            else
            {
                EnableCloseButton();
            }
            label6.Text = "Currently " + 
                 listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
        }
    }
    catch { }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is it just not writing?

Comment: You are probably getting an error, and this: `catch { }` is hiding it from you

Comment: No errors @Gusdor. If i enter  anything into the textbox it will go into the listbox and if i check the textbox it will have been entered and saved. but if i do the same thing only hold the power button down and power back on it will have saved the text. But on second or third try it will not work.

Comment: If you manually delete the file after the first attempt, does it work on the second try?

Comment: no i have tried that also.
This used to work before i added in the timer to re-focus to the texbox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to make sure you release all resources.

Replace

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName);
foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
    sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());

sw.Close();
```

with

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName))
{
    foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
        sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `Stream.Flush()` on the `FileStream` before you close it?

Answer (score 0):

i do not know the scenario you have triggered the issue, but this line
       if (lastTwoChars != "*") return;
will jump over the following logic, so you write may never be called.
p.s. you do not actively call Flush before Close.

Comment: the text that is entered always has "**" at the end and it does call the following logic. As I stated above, the code will write to the text file normally.It will write to it when each line is entered. but it writes once if the tablet is powered off, but if i then try to power it off a second time when text is entered it does not work. but i had it working

Comment: then how you verify the data has been written? use some editor to open the file? if so, just guess, the file has been locked to write. try to write some log with the exception, catch {} is not good for debugging.

Comment: the program has a minimized version, which every time a line of data has been written, i open the text file the data appears, then i repeat.
This shows the text file is saving the data , but when powered off and back on, somehow does not have the data even after having saved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working sample from my code, appends in the file.

```
using (StreamWriter xyz = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(File_Path, "xyz.txt"), true, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
                {
                xyz.WriteLine("ABC"); // or whatever you want
                //xyz.WriteLine(item);
                xyz.Flush();
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps.